# UniVerse TCL line JOIN syntax

Tags: sql

I am trying to JOIN two tables; PRODUCT AND PSUB.

PRODUCT contains one row of data for each PRODUCT_ID

PSUB contains multiple rows of data for each PRODUCT_ID transaction, however PRODUCT_ID is not multivalued.

Here is the output of both tables on two specific IDs.

[image]

I would like to JOIN the tables, to run two reports:

1. Show PRODUCT_IDS that are in PRODUCT table, however, exclude those that are in PSUB table.
2. Show all PRODUCT_IDs that are in PSUB table, however, exclude those that are in PRODUCT table.

Here is what I attempted to use to get a COUNT, however, query basically locked up:

SELECT COUNT (*) FROM PRODUCT, PSUB WHERE PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID <> PSUB.PRODUCT_ID;

Here are the individual COUNT queries.

[image]

Thank you for your help in advance!!

Tom

Answer (score 0):

1) Example using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`, can be also done just by using joins, etc.

```
SELECT
p.product_id
FROM
product p
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT product_id FROM psub );
```

2) Just like first example, you need only to swap the tables.

another solution using `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT
p.product_id
FROM
product p
WHERE p.product_id NOT IN ( SELECT product_id FROM psub );
```

and another one using `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT
p.product_id
FROM
product p
LEFT JOIN psub b ON p.product_ID = b.product_id
WHERE
b.product_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: thank you, attempted, however, in both queries, returned "0 records listed".

Comment: I've added another solution, if that doesn't works, check only the subquery, if it returns at least something).

Comment: I tested against a specific ID.  SELECT p.product_id FROM product p LEFT JOIN psub b ON p.product_ID =  b.product_id WHERE b.product_id = 1771356;  Question: is it possible, the query needs an "unnest" since there can be multiple records in PSUB for every one record in PRODUCT related to the same Product_ID.  >> Seems to be running into a LOOP problem, had to kill the process.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the query. This is very basic SQL join. It can't run into loop. It might run for a while though, even minutes, if the tables are large (or lacking proper indexes).